# Galaxy S2 USB port blown, need to transfer files via wifi

Tags: file-transfer, wifi-direct

Power supply port on my Galaxy S2 is shot and I need to backup all of my data/content/contacts, but can't do it via USB.  I've tried a couple wifi transfer apps, but am not convinced the transferr is viable. (I can see some stuff, but others are 'Directories' or 'Executables' and won't 'Unzip' on my mac.

Phone is Samsung Galaxy S2, model SCH-R760X, Android vers. 4.1.2.

IIRC, I'd tried using SmarterDroids 'Wifi File Transfer' and have looked at several others, but would appreciate advice from other users.

I would note that I'll want to transfer the data to a mac, then eventually an iPhone 5.

I can provide more info if needed.

Any suggestions or solutions for this situation?
Thanks,
K

Comment: Hi and welcome! Is it possible to use Samsung's "Kies via Wi-fi" on a phone as old as yours -- whether using Mac OS or whether using Windows on Boot Camp?  Alternatively, can you back up all your data to the cloud (to Google Contacts and a photo-sharing website and whatnot) and then restore it to the iPhone?

Comment: Also: What data do you want to back up? Contacts and what else? Please [edit] your question and tell us. Please go into excruciating detail, if possible.

Comment: Or can you somehow use Bluetooth to sync your data?

Answer (score 0):

Total commander with the LAN plug-in will let you copy the files to a regular shared drive, or you can use the wifi tool to setup a temporary custom share with another phone/tablet - it creates a share then displays a QR code which the other device then scans. Fast, free and easy. You will need to zip it first and create a shared drive on the MAC (which doesn't need any software but you can install it if you want).

Total commander https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander

LAN plug-in https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.tcplugins.LAN

Root is not needed and zip/unzip is included.

Contacts you should be able to sync with an email account and pull from there to the iPhone